# Python Keyring ,how to pass master password

Tags: python, python-keyring

Is there any way to pass master password automatically/programmatically. as per the below code we have to input password manually, can we avoid this

```
import keyring 
keyring.set_password('testuser','testuser','testpassword')

test = keyring.get_password('testuser', 'testuser')
print(test)
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by automatically? can you mention specifically

Comment: hello,    if we are using keyring  we have to input master password to retrieve sorted password, Please see the prompt.                                         `# python test12344
Please enter password for encrypted keyring:`

Comment: any option to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If this is your personal computer then I would suggest that you store your master password in a secure location like `/etc`.
For linux you can create a file like `/etc/master_passwd.txt` and store password in it (run the below command with sudo).

```
$ touch /etc/master_passwd.txt > your_password_here
```

Then in your python script you can get master password with:

```
with open('/etc/master_passwd.txt', 'r') as passwd_file:
    master_password = passwd_file.read()
```

Comment: Adding password in to profile is not a secured or suggested way. to avoid this practice only we are trying to use password vaults. i  am trying to find an unattended way to get the password to run scripts

Comment: You have to store it somewhere. I suggest that you use any encryption algorithm to encrypt the password, store it in profile. And when you need it you can again decrypt it and use it.

Comment: You are storing the master password in a secure location like /etc because only root can access those files so i think its secure

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying create one UI for executing multiple scripts for automation and these scripts are required device login credentials and login credentials are stored in the keying.                                 we can input the master password via UI. But i want to know the way to pass the master password as variable

Comment: One way or another you have to store it somewhere. If you want it more secure you can create a file in any secure directory like /etc and store password in that file and in need you can parse that file so that it is secure more getting through environment variable. Let me know if want an update to the answer

Comment: Can we pass master password as value ?from the file parser

Comment: What i am asking is different , how to pass value  master_password to master password prompt (Please enter password for encrypted keyring:)

Comment: You don't have to pass it to prompt. Just put the value of master password that you are getting from file to wherever you want. You can put it in keyring.set method to get other passwords.

Comment: `import keyring`
                                               `with open('/etc/master_passwd.txt', 'r') as passwd_file:
    master_password = passwd_file.read()
    print master_password
keyring.set_password('testuser','testuser','testpassword')

                                                             test = keyring.get_password( master_password,'testuser', 'testuser')
print(test)`   i tried this way but its failing

Comment: TypeError: get_password() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) this is the error

Comment: That's your script's problem. I would suggest next time you ask a question don't extend it too far like this. try to be specific about the problem

Comment: I provided you the solution for what is asked

Comment: this is not script problem get_password more than two arguments and solution is not  helpful any way thanks for your support

Comment: Yeah how will it be helpful when you change your requirements to too far and don't try to think about the provided solution. You have to apply the solution not blindly copy paste the code. I gave you the idea I am sure that a little knowledge of python would do here.